# Android Phonegap/Webkit/Viewport position fixed

Tags: android, css, html, cordova, css-position

i m having an issue with position fixed on an app that i m making with phonegap..
till now i thought it was operating as it should, but i found out that position fixed "breaks" under specific circumstances..
i have on top a row (div) with a couple of tabs and onclick of each tab with some javascript and css i change the main view using display property..

i found out though, that if i have scrolled down on a view, and then i select change tab, then the entire row of tabs instead of staying "fixed" on top, it moves down, and gets "fixed" on a new lower than the top position..

the main layout of my code is

```
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabwrap">a couple of divs for tabs blah blah</div>
<div id="content">main view with hide/show etc</div>
</body>
```

(i included the meta viewport tag just to point that i m using it as well)
if the main view isn't scrolled down, and it is on top, then there is no break the position fixed, and stays on top as expected..
i tried to "trick" it by adding on the onclick event of each tab this line

```
document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
```

so that it would return to top before loading next content in the corresponding div, but no success..

and the css

```
#tabwrap {height:3em; position:fixed; width:100%; }
#content { padding-top:4em; width:100%; }
```

here is a small demo from jsfiddle but dont know if it is of any use..
http://jsfiddle.net/B3Y5N/7/
i ve stripped some fo the code to make it simplier

the weird thing is, that on 2.3.5 (samsung s5570) it has no problem, and i notice the issue on 4.2.2 (nexus) while i would expect the opposite..

Comment: Can't really tell what's going on here based on your description. Can you post a jsfiddle showing your markup a little more clearly?

Comment: will try to do right now..

Comment: tested it on 4.0.3 htc evo 3d, and the problem doesn't show up...!!! till now i managed to reproduce it only on 4.2.2 nexus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here the changes that i ve made that seem to have fixed the issue..

```
 #tabwrap {height:3em; position:fixed; width:100%; top:0; left:0; z-index:100;}

 #content {position absolute; top:4em; width:100%; height:100%}
```

also removed from html document the

```
height:device-height
```

from

```
meta name=viewport tag
```